# How to generate a cylinder with a hole except by knife tool and Boolean methods

Tags: mesh, modifiers, knife-tool

[image]

This is a shape I want to generate. I know it is a very easy to generate by a knife tool and boolean method. But I want to use the extrude method to generate. a unfinished work is shown as following figure. So anyone can help me generate the two faces at the top and bottom.
I have tried many methods. all fails.
Please help me, many thanks

[image]

Comment: One more way is to use Inset tool, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48676/boolean-modifier-leaves-cutting-edge-on-face.

Comment: related: Bridge Edge Loop tool http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60548/47

Answer (score 7):

For instance :

Starting from a circle :

- Add a circle
- In edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) extrude <kbd>E</kbd> and stay in place (<kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>RMB</kbd>)
- Scale <kbd>S</kbd>
- Select all and extrude again <kbd>E</kbd>

[image]

Or from a cylinder :

- Add it
- Remove top and bottom the faces
- Then same principles as above

[image]

Or using curves :

- Add a plane
- Keep only the edges <kbd>X</kbd> the 'only faces'
- Back to object mode convert it to a curve <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then curve from mesh
- Add a bezier circle curve
- Set the previous plane as bevel object
- Tuning : move the plane vertices (or scale or other) to make the hole appear (here in edit mode, select all then grab along X)

[image]

Another one !! Using spin tool :

- Add a plane
- Keep only the edges
- In edit mode offset it (and eventually scale it)
- Go in front view (viewing the plane on its side)
- Then spin tool <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, set the rotation, the amount of steps
- Remove double (for the last step which overlaps)

[image]

Or with 2D curves (but not only quads here):

- Add a bezier circle
- Set it to 2D
- Duplicate, scale
- Convert to mesh
- Extrude

[image]

Modifiers and "non destructive way" :

- An eccentric plane
- Solidify
- Array
- Simple deform with 'bend'

[image]

Comment: +1 but a simpler way to create a square shaped curve is to add a bezier circle, set the resolution to 1 and rotate by 45° on the Z axis and apply rotation.

Comment: instead of Spin use the Screw modifier, it is non-destructive 'edit until happy'

Comment: @zeffii, yes. For the fun, added a non destructive / "full modifiers" way ; ) ... not the shortest but... (my guess, giving few technics to new users, through this 'exercise')

Comment: @zeffii, I am not seeking the shortest here (even if there is no sense to seek the longest). Considering the question (and as what is to be done is simple and quick) this is just an occasion to give some possibilities to the OP who is probably new to Blender. The shortest are certainly already given by aliasguru.

Comment: In any case, his question seems to be how to bridge the two edge loops.. not how to model a tube (in a way that we would find more convenient).

Comment: @lemon many thanks for your help. Could you give me a example for a cylinder which has two or three holes?

Comment: @ChengCheng, you mean 2 or 3 holes along the tube ?

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the impressive collection already, here are two other approaches, both having the same approach: the extrusion can be done along the normals in this case.

### approach 1: Extrude along Normals

[image: extrude along normals]

### approach 2: Solidify Modifier

[image: solidify]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen my first thought of method yet:

1. Create an open cylinder (or remove the caps from a closed one)
2. Switch to edge mode
3. Loop-select both end loops
4. Start extruding
5. Lock the cylinder's through-axis (shift-Z in the OP)
6. Get the endcap ring where you want it and accept extrusion.
7. With the inset edges still selected, use the "bridge edge loops" command

I'll see if I can't get some screenshots when I can.